# Appium Desktop terminates after booting ios simulator

Tags: ios, appium, ios-simulator, appium-desktop

I'm trying to inspect the elements of the IntegrationApp.app that comes with the WebDriverAgent project. I built the app on a simulator in xcode but when I:

- Open Appium Desktop (v1.15.1) on my MAC (v10.14.6)
- Start the server
- Select Start Inspector Session magnifying glass icon in the top right corner of the appium window
- Provide the following capability set:

```
{
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "iPad Air (3rd generation)",
  "platformVersion": "13.1",
  "app": "/Users/[MAC_USER]/Desktop/IntegrationApp.app"
}
```

- Start the session

The simulator boots up and then Appium Desktop terminates leaving the ios simulator open without the app being installed. Has anyone encountered similar issues? Any thoughts what could be causing the issue? When running `xcrun simctl list` it lists the model. Below are the appium logs:

````
[info] [35m[Appium][39m Non-default server args:
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   allowInsecure: {
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   }
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   denyInsecure: {
[info] [35m[Appium][39m   }
[info] [35m[Appium][39m Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/testuser/Desktop/IntegrationApp.app","automationName":"XCUITest","deviceName":"iPad Air (3rd generation)","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"13.1","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true}}[39m
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"/Users/testuser/Desktop/IntegrationApp.app","automationName":"XCUITest","deviceName":"iPad Air (3rd generation)","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"13.1","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true},null,null]
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1574244116561 (10:01:56 GMT+0000 (GMT))
[info] [Appium] Appium v1.15.1 creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.133.1) session
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "app": "/Users/testuser/Desktop/IntegrationApp.app",
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "automationName": "XCUITest",
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "deviceName": "iPad Air (3rd generation)",
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "platformName": "iOS",
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "platformVersion": "13.1",
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "newCommandTimeout": 0,
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "connectHardwareKeyboard": true
[debug] [BaseDriver] }
[info] [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: ba3f0114-0bfa-4e5a-8bb8-ee1d30e62166[debug] [XCUITest] Current user: 'testuser'
[info] [HTTP] [37m-->[39m [37mGET[39m [37m/wd/hub/sessions[39m
[info] [HTTP] {}
[debug] [GENERIC] Calling AppiumDriver.getSessions() with args: []
[debug] [GENERIC] Responding to client with driver.getSessions() result: []
[info] [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 5 ms - 40
[info] [HTTP] 
[info] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '13.2'[info] [iOSSim] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 11.2.1 with udid 'C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5'
[info] [XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: 'C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5', real device: false
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'xcodeDetailsRetrieved' logged at 1574244119170 (10:01:59 GMT+0000 (GMT))
[info] [BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/testuser/Desktop/IntegrationApp.app'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'appConfigured' logged at 1574244119174 (10:01:59 GMT+0000 (GMT))
[debug] [XCUITest] Checking whether app '/Users/testuser/Desktop/IntegrationApp.app' is actually present on file system
[debug] [XCUITest] App is present
[debug] [iOS] Getting bundle ID from app '/Users/testuser/Desktop/IntegrationApp.app': 'com.demo2019.IntegrationApp'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'resetStarted' logged at 1574244119179 (10:01:59 GMT+0000 (GMT))[info] [XCUITest] Not scrubbing third party app in anticipation of uninstall
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'resetComplete' logged at 1574244119388 (10:01:59 GMT+0000 (GMT))[warn] [XCUITest] Continuing without capturing device logs: iOS Simulator with udid C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5 is not running
[info] [XCUITest] Setting up simulator
[debug] [iOS] No reason to set locale
[debug] [iOS] No iOS / app preferences to set
[debug] [iOS] Setting did not need to be updated
[debug] [iOSSim] Setting preferences of C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5 Simulator to {"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true}
[debug] [iOSSim] Setting common Simulator preferences to {"RotateWindowWhenSignaledByGuest":true,"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true}
[debug] [iOSSim] Updated C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5 Simulator preferences at '/Users/testuser/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist' with {"DevicePreferences":{"C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5":{"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true}},"RotateWindowWhenSignaledByGuest":true,"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true}[info] [iOSSim] Booting Simulator with UDID C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5...[info] [iOSSim] Starting Simulator UI with command: open -Fn /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app --args -CurrentDeviceUDID C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5 -ConnectHardwareKeyboard 1[info] [iOSSim] Simulator with UDID C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5 booted in 16 seconds
[debug] [IDB] Connecting idb service to 'C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5'
[debug] [IDB] Disconnecting idb service from 'C360E349-1255-4D96-B146-13D1FD3ACDF5'```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is with idb. It seems that idb is not working properly. You need to uninstall idb completely.

```
pip uninstall fb-idb
brew uninstall idb
brew uninstall idb-companion
```

And then make sure that below commands should not give any results.

```
which idb
which idb-companion
```

Now run your code it should work fine.
Basically we don't need idb to run ios simulator